# WP Sage - Browsersync proxyUrl not working

Tags: wordpress, npm, webpack, browser-sync, roots-sage

Just wondering if anyone can help me on an issue I’ve been having with Browsersync issues with the [Sage](https://roots.io/sage/) theme for Wordpress.

In terms of my environment, I’m using Laravel Valet, which is parked in a projects directory on my machine. The site in question is in this projects direct on a .test domain and has a self signed SSL cert from Valet.

Running yarn build successfully builds the site, however when running yarn start, the files build and successfully build every time I change a JS/SCSS file with Browsersync showing `DONE Compiled in 284ms`... however Browsersync is failing to proxy the valet URL, as when I go to https://localhost:3000, Chrome loads for an extremely long time and then throws ERR_TIMED_OUT. Tried in other browsers and get the same issue.

- There is no firewall blocking that port, as tried with another app which works successfully
- Tried with and without self signed cert from Valet, and tried http and https links from Browsersync
- Tried deleting node_modules and running npm install
- Tried changing the URL of the site
- Tried a different proxyUrl in config.json
- devUrl is definitely correct
- publicPath is definitely correct as it’s building the files
- Browsersync doesn’t throw any errors

Someone on the Sage Discourse recommended downgrading browsersync too but that didn't work

Been looking at this for two days now and just hopelessly Googling… so just seeing if anyone has had this issue before?

Cheers!